# Extract in a string a pattern starting with and ending with something

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract in a string a pattern starting with and ending with something

here is the url :

http://monsite.com/articles/%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%84%d8%b3%d9%88%d9_sto3955603/description.html

In C#, how do I extract from this url the pattern `%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%84%d8%b3%d9%88%d9_` ?

The start character of the pattern is `%` and the ending character is `_`

Comment: But which `%` character? First one?

Comment: Extracting a pattern from that url will likely become much easier if you decode it.  `var decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "http://monsite.com/articles/%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%84%d8%b3%d9%88%d9_sto3955603/description.html";
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(s.IndexOf('%'), s.IndexOf('_' ) - s.IndexOf('%') + 1));
```

Output will be;

```
%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%84%d8%b3%d9%88%d9_
```

Here a <kbd>[`Demonstration`](http://ideone.com/n9HFjB)</kbd>.

If you want to check first your string has `%` or `_` charachters or not, you can use [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method like;

```
if(s.Contains("%") && s.Contains("_") && (s.IndexOf('_') > s.IndexOf('%')))
{
  // Your string has % and _ characters and also _ comes after first %.
}
```

Comment: Will work if there really *is* a `'%'` *and* a `'_'` after that in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following snippet...

> ```
> string input = "http://monsite.com/articles/%d8%a7%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%84%d8%b3%d9%88%d9_sto3955603/description.html";
> var output = Regex.Match(input, @"%[\w\d%]*_");
> Console.WriteLine(output.Value);
> ```

The output is...

> %d8%a7%d8%af%d9%85%d9%8a%d9%84%d8%b3%d9%88%d9_